# Entity Framework changing values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Ive got a value in a database

```
public int Rev { get; set; }
```

and i would like to change it to Rev+1 on each row updates, but since I am new to Entity Framework I have no idea how to program this. Could somebody please help?

Comment: Whenever you update in your code do `Rev = Rev +1`?

Comment: nowhere - I am wondering how to do this while if I update it in a setter method, I am afraid, that it will be updated everytime I call Context.Save() method with any loaded row - even if I did no changes to it.

Comment: @CodeDemen what is purpose of this field? You want to know exact number of times entity was saved to database?

Comment: Are you using codefirst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new partial class to override the SaveChanges() method on your EF object. In the SaveChanges() method you can check each entry of `YourTableEntity` to see if it was modified, and increase the Rev property if it is.

```
public partial class YourDBNameDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<YourTableEntity>().ToList())
        {
            if (entry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entry.Entity.Rev++;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would do for database first if you can't create a trigger directly on the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create triger, which will increment your field when you update your table.

You can do it by creating a class inherited from a CreateDatabaseIfNotExists or another ones which implemented [IDatabaseInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and override method Seed.

Here is a short example:

```
class CdineWithTrigger : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<RepositoryContext>
{
   protected override void Seed(RepositoryContext context)
   {
      context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YOUR SQL CORE FOR ADDING A TRIGGER");
   }
}
```